# Trying to connect my Android Client to my Computer using external IP

Tags: java, android, sockets, communication, serversocket

I'm trying to make a server-client model which a java application that will be a server, and a android app will establish a Socket connection with my server computer, in the listening port ( arbitrary chosen 50000 )

The android app register, log-in, make some information requests, and send some responses. The server program listen one or more clients and take some information from a MySQL database, and when a client ends the request prints a fiscal note of what they have bought.

and almost all works:

- a uPnP port forwarding is configured in my router
- my java program is open and listening in the right port ( port 50000 is LISTENING, in command netstat )
- my external IP is resolved in a Dynamic DNS host (I used the website no-ip),and when I ping to my host, the correct external IP is returned
- And all works, almost when my router is 'happy'...

After a while (some hours, some minutes), external access becomes inaccessible, the cause is not clear:

- the external IP do not changes ( also the local don't change )
- the port stays visible ( tested in many port-tester websites, also my program prints that someone tried a connection when checking the port)
- I can ping to my host and resolves to the correct IP ...
- the android app can connect if in the same network and using local IP (which for my computer is 192.168.1.8)

but the things become unclear when i try to execute telnet:

- telnet 192.168.1.8 50000 works    (local host)
- telnet 127.0.0.1 50000 also works (also local host?)
- telnet localhost 50000 also works (obviously local host)
- but to the external ip, and to router ip (192.168.1.1) not works, prints like that: "Connecting To 123.123.123.123...Could not open connection to the host, on port 50000 : Connect failed."
- and with telnet on external ip, without specifying port, not works prints the same of above
- (to be clear, when my router is 'happy' all telnet's works)

the java code of my server-side application that open the server, using a ServerSocket:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    try {
        Start();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Inicio.Erro("Erro no Server:"+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("SocketServerThread Parou");
    Inicio.LOG("Server Parou");
}   
public void Start() throws InterruptedException
{
    connect();

    while(KeepWaiting)
    {
        WaitClient();
    }
} 
public void connect()
{
    try {
            serverSocket =new ServerSocket(50000);
            System.out.println("my ServerSocket started");
            System.out.println("listening:\n"+InetAddress.getLocalHost()+":"+serverSocket.getLocalPort());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
public void WaitClient() throws InterruptedException{
    try {
            Inicio.LOG("Waiting Connection...");
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // blocking wait ( 99.9999% of the time in this line )
            BufferedReader buff_Reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            BufferedWriter buff_Writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            System.out.println("<Conected>");
            System.out.println("IP Client: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            Inicio.LOG("Conected -> IP Client: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            ReadThread reader_thread = new ReadThread(buff_Reader);
            WriteThread writer_thread = new WriteThread(buff_Writer);
            ConectionClient newconn = new ConectionClient(this,reader_thread,writer_thread,socket);
            Conections.add(newconn);
            System.out.println("Number of Conections:"+Conexoes.size());
            newconn.start(); // stats the thread thats holds the conection with that guest
        } catch (IOException e ){//SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("<Error>");
            Inicio.Erro("Server Stoped with Error:"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            KeepWaiting=false;
        }
        finally{
            // ends the server
        }
}
```

the code of my client-side android app that connects with the server with a Socket:

```
   @Override
public void run()
{
    try {
        connect();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void connect() throws InterruptedException
{
    try {
        exaustive_connect();
        if(connection.isConnected()&&Continue) {
            BufferedReader buff_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new myInputStream(connection.getInputStream()), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            BufferedWriter buff_writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new myOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            Reader = new ReadThread(buff_reader);
            Writer = new WriteThread(buff_writer);
            Communicate(); // method that listen and write messages.
        }
        else
        {
            ManageConection.E("ConexaoServidor","could not connect");
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        close(); // method that close the socket, reader and writer.
    }

}
private void exaustive_connect()
{
    try {
        if(!exaustive_tryconn(500))
        {
            if(!exaustive_tryconn(2000))
            {
                if(!exaustive_tryconn(5000))
                {
                    ManageConection.LOG("could not connect");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private boolean exaustive_tryconn(int timeout)
{
    connection = new Socket();
    try {
        connection.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ManageConection.IP, ip_holder.port), timeout); // tries the first host
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(connection.isConnected())return true;
    connection = new Socket();
    try {
        connection.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ManageConection.IP2, ip_holder.port), timeout); // tries the second host
            } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection.isConnected();
}
```

so I am here trying to find some solution to my problem. Any help so that I can identify where the problem is welcome -  ISP, Firewall, NAT, buggy UPnP, Blocking Proxy, etc?

What makes my router happy again is 'restart' and for a while ( couple of hours, sometimes some minutes ...) all works, and my delivery system works fine, but this make the server becomes 5 to 10 minutes off-line, and i want to this hold up to six hours without interruptions, or some clients will be disappointed with my buggy Server / Client.

---

To test if the ports are open, I also used this website http://ping.eu/port-chk/ they says that the port is open, and my program detects that someone tried a connection... so if the server of this website can connect to my server... why I cant?

---

Abhi, added the results after testing the `simple things`...

> ARP entries:

- while server working : https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/arp-entries-whileworking-png
- while server not working : https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/arp-entries-whilenotworking-png

> NAT Rules via iptables:

this might be a unix command, or somewhat because i only find information and support to view this in a unix system, after a long search i find the command 'Route print' that prints somewhat like a iptable

- while server working : https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/route-print-whileworking-png
- while server not working : https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/route-print-whilenotworking-png

> Firewall logs

while server is working appears that is allowed the connections, but when is not working the logs of firewall simply don't show anything about dropped connections... only shows lots of allows, from lots of locations, but don't trace nothing about my telnets, or when i try to connect from another client...

and when i disable the firewall, the server stays inaccessible.

> Router logs

In the router log:

- when telnet from my server machine to external ip or host, says
  `21:24:12 (since last boot) **SYN Flood** 192.168.1.8, 7269->> 179.252.7.196, 50000 (from PPPoE1 Outbound)`
- when telnet from another local machine to external ip or host, says
  `21:28:02 (since last boot) **SYN Flood** 192.168.1.5, 60810->> 179.252.7.196, 50000 (from PPPoE1 Outbound)`
- when telnet from my server machine or another local machine to my local ip, simple don't log anything about.
- when open a online portchecker, and click to check, says that is open, but router log says `21:30:17 (since last boot) **SYN Flood** 88.198.46.51, 47508->> 192.168.1.8, 50000 (from PPPoE1 Inbound)`

so is that the router log says when server is not working...

> Microsoft message analyzer tool

the print of the filtered log: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/messageanalizer-png

things to view:

- when telnet from my server machine to external ip or host, appears
  `Application\tTCP: Retransmitted SYN, original message is #1524`
- when telnet from another local machine to external ip or host, simply don't logs anything
- when telnet from my server machine or another local machine to my local ip, all works
- when open a online portchecker, put my external ip and port 50000 and click to check, says that is accessible, and in message analizer tool logs as a sucessfull link, and the interesting is that 'destination' appears to be my local ip, so how they connected to my local ip?

Comment: Try these few things - (i) look at the diagnostics log on the router and Firewall  (ii) run a network traffic analyzer such as Microsoft Message Analyzer on your server (iii) It could be that 'something' is expiring. on the router look at settings / rule that might impact the expiration

Comment: later today rebooted the router, and the server currently is working and when i see the firewall log i see that the connection is allowed, and in router log i didn't find any clear at all, also searched all settings in router, and i see that 'DHCP lease time' could be the expiring factor, but is reseted to 0 Days , 24:00 hrs when reboot the router, so the problem occurred because my router have been on since last day without reboots... i will test if this is true, if a reboot really grants 24hrs of same ip

Comment: It is unlikely to be DHCP because you observed the telnet when inside the network works using the local IP address.  Can you view the NAT rules via iptables? Also check ARP entries - when it works and when it fails. Log the network traffic on the server using a traffic analyzer http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226 - (assuming the server is running windows!)

Comment: server is running in windows 7, and ok i have tested all, added the results of 'iptables', wich i think is the command Route print, the results of arp entries, and the logs in the question.... so now the server is not reachable, and when i telnet to external ip, simple don't show anything in firewall log, and even if i turn off the firewall, stay not acessible... in message analizer with a filter to show only port 50000, the requests that i made from this machine appears as redirected and not send... and external requests simple don't appear in the log.the portchecker site calls my local ip..

Comment: So it is the external IP not responding. looks like your gateway is 192.168.1.1 ; your server machine is 1.8; external ip is 179.252.7.196? what is 88.198.46.51? You wrote"when telnet from another local machine to external IP or host, simply don't logs anything" - I guess that is fine because the Analyzer is running on your server machine, so it does not see that traffic.

Comment: Can you run analyzer on your external IP or host (179.x.x.x) and see if it receives the SYN (sent by 192.168.1.8)?